fstream open hangs when opening named pipe for writing
My C++ code opens a named pipe and calls gzip ... & at the background, with system() to get the named pipe as input and output compressed text to a file. However, after that the program hangs when opening the named pipe for writing.
Must the pipe be opened for writing before calling gzip?
Is it possible to open the named pipe for writing later (after opening it for reading)? The point is that the part for mkfifo and gzip call is in a function which I cannot modify, and the same function returns the name of the named pipe.
//...
mkfifo(pipePath, 0644);

std::stringstream strm;
strm << "gzip -c \'" << pipePath << "\' > \'" << outFile << "\' &";
system(strm.str().c_str());

ofstream fstrm;
fstrm.open(pipePath, std::ios_base::out);
//...

Other interesting fact is that sometimes the program doesn`t hang but sometimes it does.

Does system even return? Putting the gzip into the background doesn't make much sense if system waits for the shell to terminate.

Hi @yurikilochek,
Yes, the system system call returns.

I wrote a simple program to check whether "system" system call returns after calling  another program which runs infinitely in the background and yes, the system call doesn`t wait.

Rather than shelling out to an external process, why not use an embedded library, lke zlib?

Hi @RemyLebeau,
That is a restriction, we are limited to only using gzip.

May we please have a [mre]?  For one thing, we can't tell that your code is hanging where you say it is.  For another, your code substantively works for me:  std::system("cat /tmp/FIFO | tr a-z A-Z &") followed by ostream open/write/close does what I'd expect.  Finally, for what it's worth, my gzip refuses to open FIFOs and exits noisily.  That would lead to a hang in your code fragment above.

The issue is that named pipes block until both ends are open. Since gzip opens the pipe for reading, your program hangs trying to open the pipe for writing after gzip starts. To fix this, you need to open the pipe for writing before calling gzip.
Here’s a probable solution:
Pre-open the pipe for writing:
Open the pipe non-blocking for writing before calling gzip.
Close it, then reopen it later when ready to write data.
// Pre-open pipe for writing (non-blocking)
int fd = open(pipePath, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd >= 0) close(fd);

// Call gzip in the background
std::stringstream strm;
strm << "gzip -c \'" << pipePath << "\' > \'" << outFile << "\' &";
system(strm.str().c_str());

// Now open the pipe for writing (blocks until ready)
std::ofstream fstrm;
fstrm.open(pipePath, std::ios_base::out);

This ensures the pipe is ready when gzip tries to read from it. Give it a try.

Hi Covenant,
The program still hangs on fstrm.open

Named pipes require both ends to be open. If you open the pipe for writing without a reader, open() will block, and vice versa. Even with O_NONBLOCK, reopening it in blocking mode can still hang if gzip hasn’t opened the pipe yet.
To fix this, try open the named pipe for both reading and writing in the same process. This prevents blocking, allowing gzip to read from the pipe without issues.
